# Adding a data generated by JavaScript to the first column of a CSV file

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

How to add data to the first column of a CSV file containing 3 columns and 2000 rows?
The data is an array containing sequential number that I have generated using JavaScript. I'm trying to load this external CSV file using D3js.

The JavaScript for the sequential number generation:

```
var time = [];
for (var i = 1; i != 2000; ++i){ 
time.push(i);
}
```

My CSV file should look something like this:

```
time,rate1,rate2,rate3
1,34,43,11
2,65,31,00
3,56,76,32
4,23,44,98
5,...
6,...
7,...
8,...
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this when you go through the CSV data:

```
d3.csv("something.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.time = time[i];
  });
});
```